# How can I make more than one column in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code so far and it pulls the data from a CSV. It creates only a single column, but I would like the data to populate into a max of 4 columns with as many rows as necessary. How can I do this?
--Just to note, the data was originally in a spreadsheet in two columns, Name Data, and the goal is to make each cell be Name:Data.

```
var test_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
var table_data = '<table>';
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < test_data.length; i++) {
    var cell_data = test_data[i].split(",");
    table_data += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < cell_data.length - 1; j++) {
        if(i === 0) {
            table_data += '<th colspan="4">' + cell_data[j] + ":" + cell_data[j + 1] + '</th>';
        } else {
            table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[j] + ":" + cell_data[j + 1] + '</td>';
        }
    }
    alert(count);
    if (count == 3) {
        table_data += '</tr>';
        count = 0;
    } else {
        count += 1;
    }

    //table_data += '</tr>'
}
table_data += '</table>';
$('#loadData').html(table_data);
```

Comment: Why `j < cell_data.length - 1` rather than `j < cell_data.length`?

Comment: It populates with undefined values.

Comment: Rather than asking *"how can I do this"* explain the problems you have with the code shown. What is it doing? What is different than expected? Any errors? (etc) Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I ended up using. I used a counter to determine the number of columns that only open and closed a row once four pieces of data was inside of the row.

```
    var test_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table>';
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < test_data.length; i++) {
        var cell_data = test_data[i].split(",");
        if (count == 0) {
            table_data += '<tr>';
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < cell_data.length - 1; j++) {
            if(i === 0) {
                table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[j] + ":" + cell_data[j + 1] + '</th>';
            } else {
                table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[j] + ":" + cell_data[j + 1] + '</td>';
            }
        }

        if (count == 3) {
            table_data += '</tr>';
            count = 0;
        } else {
            count += 1;
        }
        //table_data += '</tr>'
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#loadData').html(table_data);
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `count` variable and use the [modulo (remainder) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) instead.

Comment: For a rough, slightly optimized, example: https://jsfiddle.net/ed3a4n5s/

Comment: On a side note, this looks like it could be more suited to a list. it's not tabular data per-se. If you serve your html as a list, then you have more flexibility to style based on different screen widths and use CSS media queries etc.

Comment: Thanks man! I kinda thought about using modulo, but went a more direct route.

Answer (score -1):

Form a proper table structure as mentioned in below example. Also i believe you should be getting a multi dimensional array as your data.in your loop you are only looking for one dimensional data . Please print your data via console.log to understand how you are getting your data to proceed further with your logic

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings2</th>
    <th>Savings3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```